# Kendo Grid cell does not change after edit

Tags: jquery, kendo-grid

In my Grid I have a pop up editor has a drop down list, but when I select an item from drop down list, in the grid it shows "Object Object", my drop down list,on the first following code I get data from Ajax to populate my grid:As you see when I select a producer from Drlist,it gives null,it happens when the value is null

```
$(document).keypress(function (e) {
    var mydata;
    var mydata_deviceType;
    if (e.which == 13) {

        var drp = document.getElementById('autocomplete').value;

        $.ajax({
            dataType: "json",
            type: "POST",
            url: "@Url.Action("turbineDeviceDetail","AdminTool")",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: JSON.stringify({ "turbine": drp, }),

            success: function (result){

                    var flg = "s";
                    $.ajax({
                        dataType: "json",
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "@Url.Action("producersDevice","AdminTool")",
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        data: JSON.stringify({ "flg": flg, }),

                        success: function (data) {
                            mydata = data;
                        }
                    })


$("#turbingrid").kendoGrid({

                    dataSource: result,

                    //editable: "inline",
                    //editable: true,
                    //height: 'auto',
                    scrollable: false,
                    //toolbar: ["save", "cancel"],
                    //sortable: { mode: "single", allowUnsort: true },

                    columns: [
                                          { field: 'DeviceIP', title: 'DeviceIP', width: '100px', id: 'DeviceIP' },
                                          { field: 'Producer', title: 'Producer', width: '80px', editor: ProductNameDropDownEditor },
                                          { field: 'Model', title: 'Model', width: '120px' },
                                          { field: 'DeviceType', title: 'DeviceType', width: '100px', editor:deviceTypesList },
                                          { field: 'Description', title: 'Description', width: '100px' },
                                          { field: 'Username', title: 'Username',width:'120px' },
                                          { field: 'Password', title: 'Password', width: '100px' },                                          
                                          { field: 'PublicIP', title: 'PublicIP', width: '120px' },
                                          { command: ["edit"], title: "&nbsp;", width: "100px" }],
                    editable: "popup",
                    edit:
                        function() {
                            document.getElementsByName("DeviceIP")[0].disabled = true;

                        },                          
                    editable: "popup"
                });



                function ProductNameDropDownEditor(container, options) {

 here is the grid:           

                    $('<input  name="Producer" data-type="string"\">')
                      .appendTo(container)
                      .kendoDropDownList({
                          dataSource: mydata,
                          dataTextField: "Text",
                          dataValueField: "Text",


                      });



                }
```

[As you see when I select a producer from Drlist,it gives null,it happens when the value is null](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XFEoE.jpg)

Comment: Post up your grid initialization code, specifically the columns array. Also, what is `mydata`? JSON? Can you post up an example of it so we can see the structure? I think you may be referencing the `dataTextField` and `dataValueField` incorrectly.

Comment: @Sandman 'mydata' is json getting by a ajax call

Comment: Paste an example of `mydata` and the grid columns definition into into your question.

Comment: So we can now establish that `Producer` is the column you are experiencing issues with. But still not example of `mydata`.. Firstly, is the drop down being populated with the `mydata` you expect to see? Secondly, is `Producer` an object or an attribute?

Comment: @Sandman its an Object,the thing is now when I do dataValueField: "Text.Producer", i can change grid value with a correct value,but if i do this, when i open the pop up edit,the Drop down list is not selected the default value in the cell anymore,did i make my point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on what has been identified above, I believe you are missing a [`template`](http://docs.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/helpers/grid/configuration#template) attribute on the column definition for `Producer` which is used to specify the data to be displayed within the object, source from this [Kendo example](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/editing-custom).

Add this `template` attribute on to your grid column definition as follows:

```
{ field: 'Producer', title: 'Producer', width: '80px', editor: ProductNameDropDownEditor, template: "#=Producer.Text#" },
```

Additionally, you may need to actually declare a `dataSource` for the drop down control like so:

```
function ProductNameDropDownEditor(container, options) {
    var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
        data: mydata
    });
    $("<input name='" + options.field + "' data-text-field='Text' data-value-field='Text' data-bind='value:" + options.field + "'/>")
        .appendTo(container)
        .kendoDropDownList({
            dataSource: dataSource,
            dataTextField: "Text",
            dataValueField: "Text",
        });
    }
}
```

Let me know the outcome.

### EDIT

If the `Producer` object is nullable within `mydata`, you will need to perform some additional validation using a `template` function, something like:

```
{ field: 'Producer', title: 'Producer', width: '80px', editor: ProductNameDropDownEditor, template: getProducerText },

function getProducerText(dataItem) {
    return dataItem.Text ? dataItem.Text : "No producer found";
}
```

Comment: "JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'Text' of undefined or null reference", this is what I get,but I don't know why

Comment: You need to post up an example of `mydata` so I can see what the data looks like..

Comment: this is what I get from MyData, its like a array of data ,mydata[1].Text="spol" I can also take a screen shot of you want,

Comment: Sounds like `Producer` object has the ability to be null (which of course means you can't reference the `Text` attribute within). You need to handle this through the `template` function. I have updated my answer with an example of how to do this. Additionally, if the `mydata` array does not actually contain a reference to `Producer` then the functionality changes slightly (also updated in the answer).

Comment: exactly for some data I get "null" value,and when I choose a value from my drop down list in producer,i get "Object Object" and how can I make it through template?

Comment: Try the edit, using a template function, and log the value of `dataItem` in the console (`console.log(dataItem)`) and see what is inside.

Comment: Value is "null",but how can I write on this null value,my item?sorry im novice

Comment: Can you update the question with screenshots of the behavior of the grid drop down list? And explain what you want to change? **EDIT** I also updated the question with changes to the way you are initializing the drop down list (which should persist the drop down changes)

Comment: I added,can you see the pic?when you click on the link?

Comment: Yes, so the drop down contains the correct data. So the issue is with the reference to the `Producer` column field. But if you have implemented the proposed edits above correctly, then `dataItem` within the `getProducerText` function should contain an `object` as opposed to `null` (because you are seeing `[Object object]` as opposed to `null` in the column).. Can you reproduce using [Kendo Dojo](http://dojo.telerik.com/)?

Comment: yes,now I think the problem would be solved if I make my grid change the value of  "blank cell" to something like "null",possible? IF(producer.value=="") change it with "null",it should noth remain blank

Comment: The latest edit of the template function should carry out the validation needed. If the `dataItem` `Text` attribute is `null` it will return "No producer found"

Comment: I fixed it by a very stupid missing,valuePrimitive: true,now its working